# Does Amazon CloudFront check if origin (specifically S3 bucket) has changed via MD5/ETag/Other before retransferring expired objects across regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to know if there is a cost incurred for "refetching" an expired CloudFront object from an S3 bucket **if the resource object has not changed**. ie. is the object is retransferred in its entirety to each edge location, or are things like MD5-Content headers or modified times checked first before retransferring?

I'm trying to calculate the costs incurred and can't find any information on this via google or through amazons documentation.

I would like to set the Cache-Control headers to be as short a time as possible (say a few hours) so that objects can be removed/replaced reasonably quickly in places where filename versioning is not possible, without using Invalidation Requests.

If the objects are indeed retransferred in full, then obviously with hundreds of objects this solution would be too expensive to be acceptable.

On the other hand, there may be a better solution without needing to set a low value in the Cache-Control header. If so please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an object is "expired", it is removed from the cloudfront edge location.  There's therefore no way to do an MD5 or modify time check as there is no file to compare it against.

If the file has not expired, it will not check against the origin server.

ie - 
1. File *is* on the edge location - origin server not checked
2. File expires - therefore *not* on the edge location - origin server fetches it.

A short expiration time will lead to those files being removed from the origin, therefore requiring a complete refetch.